# ID token usage when using "Log in with Google" in a mobile app

Tags: authentication, mobile, server, oauth-2.0, google-signin

Suppose that I have a mobile app with a frontend and a backend server.

My understanding is that -- when a user logs in the app with "Login with google", the frontend sends a request to the google auth server, and gets back an ID token. The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/backend-auth) says that the frontend can then send the token to the backend server to establish a session. I imagine that means the token can be used in session-based authentication?

If I were to use token-based authentication (as opposed to session-based), do I just attach the ID token in every server request, and have the backend verifies it each time when processing a request? this [page](https://oauth.net/id-tokens-vs-access-tokens/) suggests the ID token should not be sent to the backend API. Which leaves me wonder what the correct procedure is for token-based authentication when using log in with Google.

So my question is: Does my server need to create an access token from the ID token from Google, and send it to the frontend, so the frontend can attach that access token in the API requests for authentication?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Login with Google is an identity provider (IDP) operation. A full OAuth solution, including an authorization server (AS) looks like this:

- Mobile app uses system browser to redirect to AS
- AS returns a redirect response to the system browser, which routes to the IDP
- User signs in at the IDP
- IDP returns an authorization code to AS
- AS swaps it for IDP tokens and carries out validations
- AS issues a set of tokens to the app. This includes an access token (AT) with whatever scopes and claims are needed for business authorization to work.
- Mobile app sends AT in API requests
- API authorizes using scopes and claims from the access token

So ideally plug in an authorization server, to get this out-of-the-box behaviour. Another option is to implement your own token service, and issue your own tokens. That is less recommended though, since it requires more detailed understanding of the underlying security.

Comment: Thanks Gary! Is the "authorization code" returned by IDP basically an ID token in this [doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/backend-auth)?
Also, is there any know authorization server that does this out-of-the-box?

Comment: The authorization code is a result returned to the browser. It is then swapped for tokens. Most AS software will support Sign In with Google. Eg cloud platforms provide one, there are free Docker based ones or paid options. It is worth playing with a couple to see which best meets your requirements.

Comment: In terms of how you write your mobile app with an authorization server, you just need to run a code flow that connects to the AS using the AppAuth pattern - as in [my blog post](https://authguidance.com/android-setup/). The AS will do the rest.